# How to set which version of python sublime text uses

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have been teaching myself python and started out using python 2.7.5 and Sublime Text 2.  I recently enrolled in a class and they are using python 3.4. I downloaded and installed python 3.4 onto my mac, but am having trouble figuring out how to make Sublime Text use python 3 instead of 2.7. I used..

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

to determine which version of python ST was using.  It reports back with 2.7.5.

How do I force ST to use python 3?

If I have not included enough information, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Also, the code you've written won't compile with Python 3. `print()` is now a function, there is no more `print` statement...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found [this](http://blitzprog.org/posts/how-to-make-sublime-text-2-work-with-python-3) on Google.

Create the file `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Python/Python3.sublime-build`:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

You should then be able to choose the Python3 build system.

If that doesn't work, try [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70330/how-do-i-setup-python3-3-and-sublime-text-2-correctly-on-os-x-10-8-2):

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/"
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can go to Tools -> Build System -> New Build System and copy the code there. The version is a one to one copy of the python2 build system just with the different executable. As indicated in the second snippet, you might have to adapt your path. If you e.g. installed from homebrew it's probably something like `/usr/local/bin`. You can find the path of you python version by running `which python3`.

Comment: Error trying to parse build system: Unexpected trailing characters in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Python/Pthyon3.sublime-build:1:6

Comment: That is the error I receive when trying to build with either of those set as the build system.

Comment: @Wyze Both work fine for me. What **exactly** did you do? Follow the advice of @bamboon to create your new build system within ST to ensure the file gets stored in the correct location. You will get a build system file with almost nothing in it. Overwrite everything with a copy-and-paste of the code Ryan P gave you. Save it with a good name (e.g. `Python3_Test.sublime-build`). In ST ensure you are using the build system you expect (Tools -> Build System -> [nameOfYourNewBuildSystem]). If file name is `Python3_Test.sublime-build` nameOfYourNewBuildSystem is `Python3_Test`. What happens?

Comment: I was using the old syntax.. Overlooking the details.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked creating the file ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Python/Python3.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "path": "/home/tercio/anaconda3/bin/"
}
```

The "path": "/home/tercio/anaconda3/bin/" is path that is installed the anaconda3 in my computer. Replace this information with her path.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, it looks like Sublime(4) runs "py" instead of "python" or "python3".

If you would rather it just run what python.exe is 1st in the PATH, then extract the Python package (Command Palette -> PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package -> Python).

Then do Preferences -> Browse Packages -> Python and edit Python.sublime-build

Change:

```
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
```

to:

```
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
```

and get rid of this entire block:

```
"windows": {
    "cmd": ["py", "-u", "$file"],
},
```

TLDR, you should be left with this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "cmd": ["python", "-m", "py_compile", "$file"]
        }
    ]
}
```