# No module named openpyxl - Python 3.6 - OSX

Tags: python, macos, openpyxl, python-3.6

I've installed `openpyxl` from the Terminal using

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```

without any problems. I've even double-checked by simply running `import openpyxl` from the Terminal window once Python is running, and it imports no problem.

The problem starts when I try and import `openpyxl` from a script I'm building to work with a spreadsheet. I'm using Sublime Text and can't even get past the `import openpyxl` at the beginning of the script without running into the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/wcw/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in 
>           import openpyxl
>       ImportError: No module named openpyxl

How can this be happening? I know I've installed `openpyxl` correctly from the Terminal window without any errors so how can my script not find the module?

Comment: try to print out `python3.4 -m pip freeze`

Comment: and see if there is what are you looking for

Comment: did you run your `test.py` with python2?

Comment: @Will: yeap, you should

Comment: @Tiny.D: I'm not sure...the build system in Sublime is just set to "Python." How can I find out if this is really Python2?

Comment: @Will check your python version first, then refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161604/how-to-set-which-version-of-python-sublime-text-uses

Comment: @Tiny.D: that must be it. ST is reporting version 2.7 so I need to force it to use 3.6 instead. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Will great, glad you find the right solution :)

Comment: @Tiny.D: you should probably write an answer or it may be OP

Comment: @AzatIbrakov thanks :) i think the links answer will provide all guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do:

```
pip3 install --user openpyxl
```

Doing the `--user` worked for me when I tried to run my `.py` files with *matplot lib* modules which worked in `3.5` but not in `3.6`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I've installed the openpyxl succesfully via Anaconda

```
!pip3 install --upgrade openpyxl
```

> Collecting openpyxl   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/8c/83563c60489954e5b80f9e2596b93a68e1ac4e4a730deb1aae632066d704/openpyxl-3.0.3.tar.gz
>   Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jdcal in
>   /Users/a18301335/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from
>   openpyxl) (1.4.1) Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade:
>   et_xmlfile in
>   /Users/a18301335/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from
>   openpyxl) (1.0.1) Installing collected packages: openpyxl   Found
>   existing installation: openpyxl 1.8.6
>       Uninstalling openpyxl-1.8.6:
>         Successfully uninstalled openpyxl-1.8.6   Running setup.py install for openpyxl ... done Successfully installed openpyxl-3.0.3

But when I try to use tat library I get an error No module named openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

If I try to import openpyxl in Terminal, I don't have the error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This may be overly simplistic, but I had the same problem. I installed the module successfully but `import openpyxl` resulted in an error. I needed to close IDLE and start a new session. After that, my import command worked just fine.