# scrapy works on command line,but not sublime

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

i am using sublime texteditor3,when i'm building files nothing is actually done,when i run from command line it works fine,do i need to install packages on sublime to run there or what should i do?(i am using python 3.7 on windows)

this is the code from scrapy site

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

i don't get error but no files are created when i run in sublime.

Comment: How are you running this in sublime?

Comment: ctrl-b ,i'm not sure i understand your question

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161604/how-to-set-which-version-of-python-sublime-text-uses

Have you set up a file explaining what version of python to use?

Comment: @Lewis 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run the spider directly from sublime.

You have to create additional python file with content

```
from scrapy import cmdline    
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl spider_name".split())
```

Change it's working directory with scrapy project directory and then run it.

Comment: doesn't work,getting the same error as before `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wikiSpider'`

Comment: It seems it is working directory problem.
Change running directory where your scrapy.cfg file is saved and it will work.